# TRIM from right to first space

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to do a TRIM from the left of a string until the first empty space.
So `model.ProductRecord_Name` returns the string "4 - Mars"
so instead of `model.ProductRecord_Name = model.ProductRecord_Name.Trim();`

Is there anything like:

```
model.ProductRecord_Name = model.ProductRecord_Name.TrimFromRightToFirstSpace
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: You can use substring()

Comment: not clear what you're asking for, please give concrete example

Comment: What do you mean _until the first empty space_?  Are you looking for the inverse of a `Trim()` function?  Please give an example of your string before and after the function.

Comment: A combination indexOf and subString would do that in Java, I would guess it is the same thing in C#.

Comment: What string would yuo like instead of "4 - Mars"?

Comment: you question does not make seanse

Comment: Please reformulate your question and provide examples.

Comment: It's worth rereading your question before posting from the POV of someone who has no idea what you want - or get someone nearby to read it for you. Either way you hopefully end up rewriting it so that someone new to the problem can understand it with no other information.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything like:

I would say no

A method that would perform what you (maybe) want (not sure if you want right or left)

This is left :

```
    public string TrimFromLeftToFirstSpace(string s)
    {
        return s==null || s.IndexOf(' ')==-1
            ? s 
            : String.Join(" ", s.Split(' ').Skip(1).ToArray());
    }
```

This is right :

```
    public string TrimFromRightToFirstSpace(string s)
    {
        if (s == null || s.IndexOf(' ') == -1)
            return s;

        var split = s.Split(' ');
        return String.Join(" ", s.Take(split.Length-1).ToArray());
    }
```

I guess a regex would be even better fit for the job

It should be something like (far from being a regex ninja)

`^((?:[^\s]*\s)*)(?:[^\s]*)$` for the right trim

and

`^(?:[^\s]*\s?)(.*)$` for the left trim

the results being in the first captured groups

Answer (score 1):

`string.TrimStart()` for trimming from left. Would trim `"   4 - Mars    "` to `"4 - Mars    "`

`string.TrimEnd()` for trimming from right. Would trim `"     4 - Mars      "` to `"     4 - Mars"`

`string.Trim()` for trimming both left and right. Would trim `"     4 - Mars    "` to `"4-Mars"

Comment: I suspect OP does not want to trim at all given the "to first space"  and the example string "4 - Mars" which _is_ trimmed already :)

Comment: Its confusing @oerkelens I don't know what the OP is trying to say then..

Comment: I think the comments show that the question is confusing most people :)

Comment: In a way @oerkelens he wants it trimmed only from the left side of the string, and then he says trim only right until first empty space(I am sure he meant until first non-empty character). He doesn't seem to be a native speaker of the english language(like me)